# Wikipedia's pseudocode for Breadth-first search: How could n's parent be u if "n is adjacent to u"?

Tags: pseudocode, breadth-first-search

Studying the [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm, I encountered the following pseudo-code:

```
 1 Breadth-First-Search(G, v):
 2 
 3     for each node n in G:            
 4         n.distance = INFINITY        
 5         n.parent = NIL
 6 
 7     create empty queue Q      
 8 
 9     v.distance = 0
10     Q.enqueue(v)                      
11 
12     while Q is not empty:        
13     
14         u = Q.dequeue()
15     
16         for each node n that is adjacent to u:
17             if n.distance == INFINITY:
18                 n.distance = u.distance + 1
19                 n.parent = u
20                 Q.enqueue(n)
```

My question is regarding line 19 (n.parent = u):

How could n's **parent** be u if "n is **adjacent** to u"?

Comment: Parent means the previous node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parent is by definition adjacent to its children, they wouldn't be children without the connection. But that's not what this is about. The parent pointers are something completely separate from the structure of the graph, it's something new you're building up that keeps track of from where a node was first reached.

Comment: Thank you. Key to my understanding is *"A parent is **by definition** adjacent to its children"*. Indeed, I was wondering about the use of the term "parent" here. Wouldn't `n.first_reached_from` be a better name for that attribute? +1 and accepting.

Comment: @JaySouper that would be a reasonable name, but parent isn't completely random: they will form a tree with "reversed edges" (ie from child to parent)